# How to build a notification in android and implement click listener?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hello friends i am creating mp3 player application my application is successfully build i want implement click event notification when user goes on background they control media from notification panel my notification also build successfully but problem is that how control music and change image on notification .addaction() when user click on pause the image change to play and when song is play image back change to pause and media player is also  and  i am also want get  songs title, and artist here my code you can easily understand!

```
public void play(int songindex) {
song = songList.get(songindex);

try {

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + song.getGetpath());
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, uri);
     title.setText(song.getTitle());
    artist.setText(song.getArtist());

     notificationTitleText=title.getText();
    notificationDescText=artist.getText();
    handler = VisualizerDbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getApplicationContext(), mediaPlayer);
    audioVisualization.linkTo(handler);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setMax(100);
    updateProgressBar();

    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        play_main.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pause_main.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation aniRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        rotate.startAnimation(aniRotate);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {


                if (checked) {
                    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } else if (isShuffle) {
                    // shuffle is on - play a random song
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                    play(currentSongIndex);
                } else {
                    // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
                    if (currentSongIndex < (songList.size() - 1)) {
                        play(currentSongIndex + 1);
                        currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                    } else {
                        // play first song
                        play(0);
                        currentSongIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


} catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

}

```
public  void  shownotification(){
    Bitmap largeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dog);




    Notification channel = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID_1)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitleText
            )
            .setContentText(notificationDescText)
            .setLargeIcon(largeImage)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_like,"like",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev,"prev",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause,"pause",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next,"next",null)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_dislike,"dislike",null)
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().
                    setShowActionsInCompactView(1,2,3))
            .build();



    mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(1,channel);

}
```

gettext()method is working fine but it work on first when any clicked event is happen if song play oncomplete and next song is not get text value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are playing songs from an Activity but this will also work for a service.

Put this in your activity or service

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("com.mypackage.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC")){
            //Do whatever you want. Ex. Pause
        }
        //Similarly this can be done for all actions
    }};
```

Make your show notification method like this

```
public  void  shownotification(){
Bitmap largeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.dog);

Intent pauseIntent = new Intent("com.mypackage.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC");
PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, pauseIntent, 0);
// Similarly you can create an intent and pending intent pair for each action you want just change the string in intent constructor

Notification channel = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID_1)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTitleText
        )
        .setContentText(notificationDescText)
        .setLargeIcon(largeImage)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_like,"like",null)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev,"prev",null)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause,"pause",pausePendingIntent)  //like this attach every action with respective pending intent
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next,"next",null)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_dislike,"dislike",null)
        .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
        .setShowActionsInCompactView(1,2,3))
        .build();

mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(1,channel);}
```

Comment: kumar Manas do i need to register this mainfest? i apply thiis code but nothing is happened?

Comment: Yes, you need to register your broadcast listener in the manifest.

Comment: May i get your  facebook id?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add one more thing to @Kumar Manas answer

i.e We need to register reciever that is being created in activity.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("com.mypackage.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC")){
            //Do whatever you want. Ex. Pause
        }
        //Similarly this can be done for all actions
    }};
```

To register your Reciever add these lines in **onCreate()**

```
            IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction("com.mypackage.ACTION_PAUSE_MUSIC");
            registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);
```

Note: You can add as many actions you want

Answer (score 0):

You may get your answer by following this tutorial ["Android Music Player Controls on Lock Screen and Notifications"](http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/)